# Frequency List (ArrayList or LinkedList) with items over 700,000

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a list which contains elements of Person data type. What would be the best way and less consumption of time, to find the frequency of each element in the list.

The following things I have tried, results in time beyond 10min on i7, 8GB

```
    ArrayList<String> frequent = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Person E: myList2)
    {
        int frequency = 0;
        //int frequency = Collections.frequency(myList2, E); 

        for (Person e : myList2)
        {
            if (E.getPassName().equals(e.getPassName()))
                frequency++;
        }
        if (frequency >= times)
            frequent.add(E.getPassName());
    }
```

Also, the Collections always results to the VALUE 1, even if there are duplicates in the LinkedList.

Comment: `Collections.frequency()` returns 1 because it compares every item with `E`, not every item's `passName` with `E`'s `passName`.

Comment: I am gonna take a wild guess: you didn't override the equals() in Person? The Collections.frequency should do what you want **if** equals() is correct. You perform a custom equals in your own implementation. Move this to Person.equals();

Comment: So, what would be a better way?

Comment: @user3337714 As i said: override the equals() in Person. While you're at it: also update hashCode()

Comment: @user3337714 I do overwrite, But Collections.frequency is not working. :(

Comment: @user3337714 FYI, the accepted way of saying "thank you " is the upvote here, but you're welcome ;)

Comment: @Joffrey I totally understand. But being new, I can't up vote since I am not ranked to that level

Comment: @user3337714 Fair enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Map<Person, Integer>` to store the frequency:

```
Map<Person, Integer> frequency = new HashMap<Person, Integer>();

for (Person person: myList2) {
    if (frequency.containsKey(person)) {
        frequency.put(person, frequency.get(person) + 1);
    } else {
        frequency.put(person, 1);
    }
}
```

or a `Map<Person, AtomicInteger>` (Since that's a mutable type, it just makes the task of incrementing frequency easier):

```
for (Person person: myList2) {
   frequency.putIfAbsent(person, new AtomicInteger(0));
   frequency.get(person).incrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: frequency.contains or
frequency.containskey // frequency.containsValue

Comment: Person contains various other data, that would be unique. I just simply want to compare the Person.getPassName()

Comment: @user3337714 You need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `Person` class, and compere the objects based on `passName`.

Comment: and use the same above code or make any changes to the same. Sorry, I am novice in Java.

Comment: @user3337714 Use the same code. Basically `Map` uses `hashCode` and `equals` method to find elements in the bucket.

Comment: I had already added the hashCode and equals and even confirmed the codes below provided by but answer still results in 0.

Comment: thank you :). It still has not resolved. But I am trying to work over it.

Comment: @user3337714 You can share the existing code if it still doesn't work. Also the overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()` method in `Person` class.

Answer (score 0):

You algorithm is `O(n^2)`. This is bad. Using `Collections.frequency` won't fix that, it just loops over the passed in `Collection` checking for `equals`. Don't use that either.

Use a `Map`, in Java 8:

```
final Map<Person, Integer> count = myList2.stream()
        .collect(HashMap::new, (map, i) -> {
    map.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum);
}, HashMap::putAll);
```

Java 7:

```
final Map<Person, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
for (final Person person : myList2) {
    final Integer c = count.get(person);
    if (c != null) {
        count.put(person, c + 1);
    } else {
        count.put(person, 1);
    }
}
```

The advantage of Java 8 method is that with one change (`stream() -> parallelStream()`) the loop will become multi-threaded.

**NB** This relies on correctly implemented `equals()` **and** `hashCode()` methods in the `Person` class. Assuming `passName` is an instance variable of `Person`, something like:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.passName);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Person other = (Person) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.passName, other.passName)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I would like to compare the NAME of Person, i.e., person.getName() and not the person object itself. The Person object contains other variables which I do not want to account for.
What do you think I can implement?

Comment: @user3337714 if two people with the same `passName` can be considered equal then implement `equals` and `hashCode` correctly, as I have suggested. Otherwise, use a `Map<String, Integer>` and put `Person::getPassName` into the `Map` rather than the person.